# My laptop connectivity gets "limited" on wifi while other devices work well

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, limited-access

Although its marked limited i cannot access the router via laptop, the solution is to reset winsock
catalog and restart the machine.
What could be the root cause? its happening around 2-3 times a day and i have to do the same thing.
I have Avast antivirus,a webscraper plugin and another vpn plugin to chrome

Comment: The first thing to do when troubleshooting such issues is to disable every app, plugin and extension that COULD interfere with your connectivity, then re-enable them one by one until you find the culprit. If this happens at regular intervals, it could be a timeout issue with your network adapter. If it happens after several minutes of inactivity, ditto, but for different reasons (ping, for example). If it happens after gaming for a while, it could be a thermal issue: A WiFi card can heat up and throttle down, which could lead to loss of connectivity. An ISP restriction can also explain this.

Comment: Thanks @Didier ..i have disabled all the plugins..it particularly happens after i keep my laptop in sleep or idle and then open to find out that its not able to connect..then i reset winsock thru cmd and restart to regain the connection..even my mu torrent client has a considerably low speed after this symptom.Its not affecting other laptops/mobiles in the network

Comment: Check your network adapter properties in Control Panel and make sure the "Allow this PC to turn off this device to save power" box isn't checked under Power management.